# Line match to trigger specific argument

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with 2 types of contents as below.

```
QJKLJFLHLKJDGFIUD 03:12:23  
JHKJFDGDSFGDFGHDF 03:15:45  
HJIK  
ASDSdSADSADSSADSA 03:30:34  
DFDF  
KWQA
```

I have 2 binaries. One is on the local computer and other is on  the remote computer.

If the line contains a timestamp, I have to call local binary and pass the line as argument to the binary.

If  the line doesn't contain a timestamp, I have to call the remote binary and pass the line as argument to the binary.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please learn to format your questions properly and use meaningful titles. You've already been shown [how to do so](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/82031/revisions) once.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus - did someone mention to the OP prior or is your edit this time what you're referring to? - Keep in mind that many people are new to SE sites and the formatting and also English isn't always everyone's native language. I agree it's annoying to have to edit for basic things though 8-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NF==2 {system("/bin/echo " $0); next;}
  {system("/bin/echo " $0 " | rev"); next;}' inputfile
```

**Edit 1:**

```
awk 'NF==2 {system("ssh user@remote kimera " $0); next;}
  {system("kimera " $0); next;}' inputfile
```

If `kimera` expects a single argument then you need `... kimera \" $0 "\""` instead.

Comment: Why would you use `/bin/echo` to print in `awk`?

Comment: Thank u hauke for d reply... Suppose we have a binary named kimera both on local system and on remote system with host name ghostprotocol... How do we achieve above scenario..

Comment: @jordanm That's not for printing but just a dummy command.

Comment: Hi Hauke, your second reply works. I have a slight change in the requirement. as and when i process each line in awk, i want to write that line to a file. I have to pass that file as input to the binary. example: if I write the line to output file output1. then i have to call the binary as kimera -f output1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there can only be one or two fields, and that all lines with two fields contain time stamps, you could do this in `bash`:

```
while read string date; do 
   ## If there are two fields, $string and $date, launch remote command
   if [[ $date ]] ; 
     then ssh user@remote kimera "$string $date"; 
   ## If there is only one field, no date, launch the local command
   else kimera $string; fi; 
done < file
```

---

If you can have different numbers of fields and need to actually check for a time stamp in the format of NN:NN:NN, use this instead:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; 
          if(/\d+:\d+:/){system("ssh user@remote kimera $_" )}
          else{system("kimera $_" )}
' file
```